# Check if input control has certain type of vallidator in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I have component that wraps input field. In the component i receive the `Control` object from `@Input() inputControl: Control;`. In the template i have span that shows message if input field in the component is not required.

```
<span
  class="input-label-caption">
  (optional)
</span>
```

and the input

```
<input
    *ngIf="inputMode=='text' || inputMode=='email'"
    type="{{inputMode}}"
    [ngFormControl]="inputControl"
    placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
    class="input-text"
    [disabled]="inputDisabled"
    [ngClass]="{
    'inverted': inverted
    }">
```

How can i read form `inputControl` object if it contains `Validators.required`?
I want to know if i can used it like this for example

```
<span
  class="input-label-caption"
  *ngIf="!inputControl.validators.required"
  >
  (optional)
</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use this expression:

```
<span
  class="input-label-caption"
  *ngIf="!inputControl.errors?.required"
>
  (optional)
</span>
```

The `errors` attribute contains one entry per name of validator that failed.

I use the Elvis operators for the `errors` attribute since it can be undefined if there is no validation error.

**Edit**

Following your comment, I think that you can check a "required" validator using the === operator with the `Validators.required` function directly. In fact a validator is simply a function and the `Validators.required` function is used for "required" validation.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
this.hasRequiredValidator = (this.inputControl.validator === Validators.required);
```

In the case where the `validator` attribute is an array, you need to extend a bit the test to check if the `Validators.required` function is present in the array.

Now the code in the template would be:

(optional)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry and thanks for your help. I tried your idea and it works partially. When the component is initialized it works fine because there is error present in `Control` object but when i write something in the input `inputControl.errors` looks like this `{ required: false }` because there is no longer error in the input and the message is shown again.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem ;-) I think that you should test the validator directly. I udated my answer accordingly... Hope it will fix your issue...

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for your help. This line of code did the trick `if(this.inputControl.validator && this.inputControl.validator(Validators.required)) { this.inputRequired = true;  }` i'm gonna left this as unanswered for couple of days because maybe someone will give more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: You won't be able to use this if the function takes in a parameter, will you?

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get the above to work which isn't surprising given the changes to Angular since Jan. With the latest version of Angular (2.2.0)you will need something like this in your class.

```
  get required(): boolean { 
    var _validator: any = this.inputControl.validator && this.inputControl.validator(this.inputControl);
    return _validator && _validator.required;
  }
```

This will also handle the case where you have multiple validators in a reactive form e.g.

```
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]
```

Comment: I tried to test your code but _validator is allways null, I'm using angular 2.4, is there any changes to use your code on angular 2.4? thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem creating a new FormControl and pass it as an argument to validator....like this:  get required(): boolean { 
    var _validator: any = this.inputControl.validator && this.inputControl.validator(new FormControl());
    return _validator && _validator.required;
  }  I dont't know if it is the best way but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but what worked for me was to check if the control has the `validator` or `asyncValidator` methods. This way you know if the control has some sync validator or some asyncValidator.
Then if you want to know which validators you call the method.

**Sync Validatos:**

```
const getSyncValidators= (control: FormControl) => {
   if(control.validator) {
     return control.validator({} as AbstractControl);
   };
};
```

**Async Validatos:**

```
const getAsyncValidators= (control: FormControl) => {
   if(control.asyncValidator) {
     return control.asyncValidator({} as AbstractControl);
   };
};
```

For async validators you get an observable you can't see the name of the async Validators.

If you only want to know it has an async validators it is a simple way to do it.

Always check that control.validator or control.asyncValidator exists due to controls without any validator will throw an error due to the function does not exist.