# How can I bind to property in projected content in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I want to use content projection, but I can't bring it to work.

The HTML is

```
<form [ngFormModel]="demoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <my-form-group myLabel="Some Label">
    <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="demoForm.controls['someInput'] [required]="true">
  </my-form-group>
</form>
```

The Component is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-group',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>{{myLabel}}<span *ngIf="required">&nbsp;*</span></label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    `
})

export class MyFormGroup {
  @Input() myLabel: string;
}
```

How can I bind the *ngIf condition in the span to the required property of projected input element? The goal is to show the asterisk in the outer component, when [required] becomes true.

**Edit:** I made a - not working - [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/J3GaJHAjvBeTs3taTtvQ?p=preview) to show what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You could reference the control within the `ng-content` using the `ContentChild` decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-group',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>{{myLabel}}<span *ngIf="required">&nbsp;*</span></label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyFormGroup {
  @ContentChild(NgFormControl) state; // <------
  @Input() myLabel: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.required = (this.state.validator === Validators.required); // <-------
  }
}
```

This way you will have access to the control properties and specially the validator. If you have the `Validators.required` one, your input is required.

What is not clear to me is that you use `ngFormControl` and the `required` attribute. I think that you should use the following rather:

```
this.demoForm = formBuilder.group({
  someInput: ['', Validators.required ]
});
```

See this question for more details:

- [Check if input control has certain type of vallidator in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859870/check-if-input-control-has-certain-type-of-vallidator-in-angular2/34859926#34859926)

See also this article (section "Form component for fields") for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

**Edit**

After having dug a bit, you can check that the `RequiredValidator` directive is applied on the input:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-group',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>{{myLabel}}<span *ngIf="required">&nbsp;*</span></label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyFormGroup {
  @ContentChild(RequiredValidator) requiredValidator; // <------
  @Input() myLabel: string;

  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.required = (this.requiredValidator != null); // <-------
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hallo Thierry, thank you for your quick answer. I want to allow change of attributes, like required or disable, controled by my outer component. If I would add Validators.required in my formbuilder.group, I would hardcode that, wouldn'd I? It seems to me, I can not use your compare with "this.state.validator", because there is no validator function available when I' using the attribute for that?

Comment: You're welcome! So you want to use the inline declaration of validators with `ngControl`, not the use of `FormBuilder`? I ask because you use `ngFormModel` and `ngFormControl`...

Comment: I think I get it ;-) You can check if the `RequiredValidator` is applied on the input. I updated my answer accordingly ;-)

Comment: Unfortunatly I still cannot bring this to work. I made a plunkr to show what I mean. https://plnkr.co/edit/J3GaJHAjvBeTs3taTtvQ?p=preview - this.requiredValidatoris an empty object in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Because I got no more answers until now, in the meantime I tryed to find a solution. I found one, which is not really satisfying. I simple inject "required" also into the outer container. I don't like this solution, because a have inject the value twice.

And at the end I sticked with a new problem. But here is the code first:

```
<my-form-group myLabel="Hallo" [myRequired]="demoForm.controls['required'].value">
    <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="demoForm.controls['hallo']" [required]="demoForm.controls['required'].value">
    errors: {{demoForm.controls['hallo'].errors | json}}
</my-form-group>
```

And the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-group',
  template: `
  <div class="form-group">
    <label *ngIf="myLabel">{{myLabel}}<span *ngIf="myRequired">&nbsp;*</span></label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>`
})
export class MyFormGroup {
  @Input() myLabel: string;
  @Input() myRequired: boolean;
  @ContentChild(NgFormControl) ctrl;
}
```

My next problem now is: Validation is not updated. Please see this Plunkr showing also the input's errors object.
https://plnkr.co/edit/cBqSB6DX68EnqvnyqrGg?p=preview

Is there any solution for this? (or is it simply a bug?)
And, if one has a better solution then mine, I would enjoy.