# Angular reactive forms get the currently set validation rules from AbstractControl

Tags: angular, validation, angular-directive, angular-reactive-forms

What I'm trying to achieve is automatically set a asterisk on a input when a given control has the validation rule 'required'.

Component ts:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

Component template:

```
<label>
    <span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" [appRequiredAsterisk]="form.get('name')" formControlName="name" id="name">
</label>
```

My Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appRequiredAsterisk]'
})
export class RequiredAsteriskDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() appRequiredAsterisk: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Append Asterisk here..
    }
}
```

I can't find a way to see if the validation rule 'required' is set on the `AbstractControl appRequiredAsterisk`. How can I do this?

Comment: Look at this answer, I think it might be helpful in your case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40642955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:-

```
let isRequired = appRequiredAsterisk.errors['required'];

if (isRequired) {
    //show asterix
}
```

**Edit:**

Issue with above is that obviously when the error disappears  so will the asterix.

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838108/get-validators-present-in-formgroup-formcontrol) which actually gives you the validators

```
let nameControlVald = this.form.controls['name'].validator('');
console.log(nameControlVald, "validators");
```

Looks like this is the best way to solve your issue. So pass in `this.form.controls['name']` to the directive and set the above then check if `required` exists.

Comment: Thanks but this is when there is an error. Not when the rule is set. I need to add the asterisk when the field is set to required.

Comment: Ah ok sorry got the wrong end of the stick - will update my answer

Comment: Updated my answer